# Winflash does not support this BIOS update ASUS

Tags: windows, bios

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> ```
> C:\Users\Admin>C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\WinFlash\WinFlash.exe \nodate
>
> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

Comment: This question body as of right now doesn't match the title at all. I see you added a new image of the actual error you are getting. Looking at it, you probably downloaded a wrong firmware for your bios.

Comment: @Ramhound oh, i thought he managed to fix the CMD command and after the run it throwed the error in the title but looking closely it seems to be 2 distinct problems.

Comment: yes I forgot the '' ''

Comment: I run WinFlash with the /nodate message erreur : parametre are not valide ??

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to run the ASUS firmware update tool.

Your attempting to run a program from a path with a space.  Change your directory to the folder containing the application then run the application.

That will solve the “is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.” error.

It appears you are also trying to apply an incompatible firmware file.  Selecting a compatible update will resolve that problem.

You can also run the command but add the quotes that are necessary.  The quotes are necessary due to the space in the **Program Files** directory.

```
“C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\WinFlash\WinFlash.exe” /noupdate
```

Comment: message erreur : parametre are not valide

Comment: yes I did that , the same problem  parametre are not valide  C:\winflash>WinFlash.exe /noupdate